# Stop if reach 404 when paging with unknown total

Tags: scrapy

I'm a newbie here so forgive my question,

so I have a url http://example.com/news?count=XX), I want scrapy to go over all count (1,2,3,4,5,) till it reach an empty page (no html) or 404 page

my issue the total count are unknown so I'm not sure how I can tell scrapy to work like this:

```
http://example.com/news?count=1 ===> found data, save it
http://example.com/news?count=2 ===> found data, save it
http://example.com/news?count=3 ===> found data, save it
....
....
....
http://example.com/news?count=X ===> no data found, stop here.
```

Comment: there is no direct way to tell scrapy to run like that, there should be a new request per url, please read the [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Comment: I was hoping not to get this answer :), thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just code a spider to do it:

```
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "example"
  allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
  start_urls = ["http://example.com/news?count=1"]
  count = 1

  def parse(self, response):
    ... make your magic! ...
    self.count = self.count + 1
    next_url = response.url[:-1] + str(self.count)
    yield scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

Obviously you must improve the logic in `next_url` if you want `count > 9`.